# How to change color for every id exist in responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change color for every id exist in responseText

```
if element id exist in responseText for every id exist
$(this id).css('background', '#f38585');
```

id like this (array no single)

- **1330473**
- **1234470**
- **1330479**
- **1330474**

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open('GET', 'bookmark.php', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'text';
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onload = function () { 
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            Change_color();
        }
    };

    function ID() {
        $('.image-item').each(function() {
            var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
            var id = href.split('id=').pop();
            console.log(id);
        });
    }

    function Change_color() {
    // change color for every id exist in responseText
    }
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Your using jquery, in some parts of your code, it would be best to use jquery for your ajax call, is there a reason why you have written a native one?

Comment: And what's the HTML that you're working with?

Comment: The question requires more detail...

Answer (score 0):

You can just fetch the array from the server using jquery, assuming your server is returning a true array ["#1","#2","#3"] join them into a string separated by commas then pass that into jquery and manipulate the elements.

```html
//
// This does the http request
//
$.ajax({
  url: 'bookmark.php'", 
  success: function(result){
      //
      // You can pass a comma sep list of ids to jquery so 
      // we just join your array from the server
      // 
      // since your ids are just a number we need to append a # 
      // so jquery can understand what we are looking for
      //
      var ids=[]; 
      result.forEach(function(id){ids.push("#"+id)});
      // 
      // we now have a array like this #1,#2,#3 which we join into a string!
      //
      $(ids.join(",")).css('background', '#f38585');
}});
```

Comment: I have edited my solution as from your question it seems your file contains a list (array) of id's so in order for jquery to locate these in the dom we need to append a hash, further jquery can apply your changes to multiple ids in one go if you pass them as a comma separated string.